# Installing problems with 14.04 alongside Windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows, windows-7, system-installation

I've tried to install 14.04 with a DVD. First the 64-bit version. It went all fine until I was asked how I wanted it installed. I chose alongside Windows 7, and it asked me to remove the installation device and press Enter. I removed the DVD, pressed Enter, and the computer rebooted, but with Windows. Nothing else happened, I could just use Windows as normal, or try again. Any idea how to fix this?

I then tried with the 32-bit version (I also have a 32-bit version of Windows 7). This one does not provide the option to install alongside Windows 7. This is strange, because I previously did it, and I'm just trying to re-install it after I restored my computer to factory settings. Is it possible that the partition for Linux is still on my drive? How can I assign it again and increase its size. If not, any idea on how to solve this is very welcome!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

When you are installing Linux, you have to make sure that your OS is properly SHUT DOWN, so don't suspend or do anything else. If your Windows is in suspended mode, Ubuntu will see the Windows partition (usually the first partition on your drive, where your MBR is stored)  as being mounted, and unless you force the unmount (you could cause problems with your Windows doing this), the ubuntu installer won't have access to write to your MBR and install the boot loader properly.
You can still use your Windows' bootloader and configure it to show you your Linux partition. I would advise to use Windows' native bootloader, but in case you're not familiar with it, you could give https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/ a try.